# Vue.js - search form with query parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js 2.6 with the `vue-router` component. I have a search form as follows:

```
<form class="search-form" @submit.prevent="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="term" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        term: this.$route.query.term,
        items: []
      }
    },
    created() {
      if (this.term != null) {
        this.search()
      }
    },
    watch: {
      '$route.query.term'() {
        this.term = this.$route.query.term
        this.search()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search: function () {
        window.axios.get('/images/search', {
          params: {
            term: this.term
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.$router.push({query: { 'term' : this.term}})
          this.items = response.data.collection.items
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return error
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I am trying to achieve with this code is the following:

1. User submits form, the `search()` function is called. The URL is updated with the query param, e.g. `/search?term=<term>`. **This is working but the `search()` function is being called twice.**
2. User carries out several searches, then presses the back button. The search field in the form is updated and the search is carried out. **This is working but the `search()` function is being called twice.**
3. User manually enters query param in the URL bar. The search field in the form is populated and the search is carried out. **This is working.**

Where the `search()` function is being called twice, this is due to the `watch()` function, which is designed to watch changes to the URL bar. I am not sure how to combine this function correctly with the `search()` function.

Answer (score 2):

In `watch`, you can compare new value with old value, and only perform search when new value is different with old value

```
watch: {
  '$route.query.term'(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal != oldVal) {
      this.term = this.$route.query.term
      this.search()
    }
  }
},
```

To make it call only 1 for 1st case, you might want to separate button click handler with real search call

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        term: this.$route.query.term,
        items: []
      }
    },
    created() {
      if (this.term != null) {
        this.performSearch()
      }
    },
    watch: {
      '$route.query.term': {
        handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal != oldVal) {
            this.term = this.$route.query.term
            this.performSearch()
          }
        },
        immediate: true 
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search: function () {
        // this is call when user click search Button
        this.$router.push({query: { 'term' : this.term}})

      },
      performSearch() {
        // perform actual searcch
        window.axios.get('/images/search', {
          params: {
            term: this.term
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.items = response.data.collection.items
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return error
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```